# Cannot verify enterprise app using distributed provisioning profile in iOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios10

I upgraded `iPad Air` device to `iOS10` and trying to trust the `enterprise app` by following the this process.

1. Installed app through IBM Worklight appcenter console
2. In settings.app > General > Profiles & Device Management, under Enterprise app selected "my app" and tap on Trust `<name>`
   When I tap on trust "Appname" just buffering for 2 seconds and showing app status as "not verified".

Provisioning profile is a valid one because I did trust the app with same PP in `iOS9.3.5` and lower versions and the app got verified successfully. 
Anyone provide the solution for this pbm.

Comment: Did you upgrade the iOS with the existing app or did you install the appcenter app after the upgrade to iOS10?

Comment: We have tested following scenarios and did not found any issues which you mentioned.

(a) Installed application from appcenter client on iOS 9.3.5 device and did trust appication procedure, Upgraded to iOS 10.0.2 via OTA.

(b) Installed application from appcenter client directly on iOS 10.0.2 and did trust application procedure.

Answer (score 1):

### iOS10 Dealing With Untrusted Enterprise Developer

Since iOS9, there is no more “trust” option for an enterprise build.

Users have to do the configuration themselves: Go to Settings - General - Profiles - tap on your Profile - tap on Trust button. [Reference](https://github.com/ChenYilong/iOS9AdaptationTips#3ios-9-dealing-with-untrusted-enterprise-developer).

but iOS10 has a little change,

Users should go to Settings - General - Device Management - tap on your Profile - tap on Trust button.

[image]

Reference: [iOS10AdaptationTips](https://github.com/ChenYilong/iOS10AdaptationTips#ios10-dealing-with-untrusted-enterprise-developer)